# Custom module chrome is not working in Joomla 4

Tags: module, joomla-4.x

I have copied the card.php file from templates/cassiopeia/html/layouts/chromes and placed it in my templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/layouts/chromes folder, and then made some modifications to the styling. Then I saved the file, selected the chrome from my module's Advanced tab, cleared my browser cache, and refreshed the browser. The custom chrome does not load.

Actually, even if I copy card.php over to my template folder and make no changes to it whatsoever, and then select it from the module's Advanced tab, it doesn't work. The card styling is not there, and the heading disappears.

When I select the Card chrome from the Cassiopeia template, it works fine.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: For me, if I choose the `default` layout at Advance tab and choose the `custom-card.php` at Module Style also in Advanced tab, it is working well. The `custom-card` layout is placed in `MYTEMPLATE/html/layouts/chromes folder`.

Comment: And if you put the `custom-card.php` layout in **mytemplate/html/mod_custom** folder, then the first 3 lines of the card layout code (that includes $displayData) has to be commented out/deleted/ or redefined, otherwise it causes some error since these data are undefined, when you use it in custom module. And you have to check for any undefined in that layout...

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled everything from scratch and now it’s working, so… never mind and thank you.